# Генерируемы столбцы в Генерируемых столбцах

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть база PostgreSQL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы столбец `saldo_out` вычислялся: `saldo_in +(debit - kredit)`. Сначала я пытался сделать это триггером:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_s_after_lns() RETURNS trigger AS $First$
BEGIN
UPDATE consolid SET  saldo_out_som   = ((SELECT saldo_in_som FROM consolid 
WHERE code = 
consolid.code) 
                                 +((SELECT debet FROM consolid WHERE code = 
consolid.code) - (SELECT 
kredit FROM consolid WHERE code = consolid.code)))
                                 WHERE code = consolid.code;
                                
                                 
UPDATE consolid SET  saldo_out_usd =((SELECT saldo_in_usd FROM consolid WHERE 
code = consolid.code) 
                                 +((SELECT debit_usd FROM consolid WHERE code 
= consolid.code) - 
(SELECT credit_usd FROM consolid WHERE code = consolid.code))) 
                                 WHERE code = consolid.code;                                     
RETURN UPDATE;
 END;
$First$
 LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER consolid
AFTER UPDATE ON consolid FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_s_after_lns();
```

Но, триггер выдает ошибку:

> подзапрос в выражении вернул больше одной строки.

Затем я решил создать генерируемый столбец, но поле `difference` уже создан как генерируемый столбец с полем `saldo_out`, и создавать генерируемый столбец в генерируемом столбце нельзя..
Можно ли это как то обойти, или может мне исправить триггер?

***Вот так создается таблица:***

```
CREATE TABLE public.consolid
(
code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
category character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
additional_score character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
name_score character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
saldo_in_som numeric DEFAULT 0,
debet numeric DEFAULT 0,
kredit numeric DEFAULT 0,
saldo_out_som numeric DEFAULT 0,
defference numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((saldo_out_som - saldo_in_som)) 
STORED,
saldo_in_usd numeric DEFAULT 0,
debit_usd numeric DEFAULT 0,
credit_usd numeric DEFAULT 0,
saldo_out_usd numeric DEFAULT 0,
difference_usd numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((saldo_out_usd - saldo_in_usd)) 
STORED,
CONSTRAINT uniq__code UNIQUE (code)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.consolid
OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: Ну ничего не понять... Покажите нынешний CREATE TABLE (форматированным текстом, ненужные поля пропустите), пример данных (пара строк), и требуемый вид данных (плюс нужный столбец) с пояснением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример вычисляемого столбца:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, 
>                    saldo_in INT,
>                    debit INT,
>                    kredit INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,10,10,5), (2,100,50,120);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | saldo_in | debit | kredit
> -: | -------: | ----: | -----:
>  1 |       10 |    10 |      5
>  2 |      100 |    50 |    120
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE test 
>     ADD COLUMN saldo_out INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (saldo_in + debit - kredit) STORED;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | saldo_in | debit | kredit | saldo_out
> -: | -------: | ----: | -----: | --------:
>  1 |       10 |    10 |      5 |        15
>  2 |      100 |    50 |    120 |        30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4aaa4ae1c2bd80318e75f54ecaea0e4a)*

Comment: У меня есть еще поле difference которое работает по принципу вычисляемого столбца и вычисляет saldo_out - saldo_in поэтому я не могу создать вычисляемый столбец saldo_out

Comment: @ВладиславЦой А за каким хреном строить цепочки? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b77e85a015caf6e9b868abee513107f8